# php - 60 seconds page timeout regardless of php settings

Tags: php, timeout, execution-time

I'm running a script that needs some time (something like 3-5 mins) but after 60 seconds the page stops loading and a blank page appears. My max_execution_time in php.ini file 120 sec and I've added theses lines before my script runs:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1800);
set_time_limit(0);
```

But still, after 60 seconds, the page stops. The strange thing is, when I trace my script process, the sql queries seems to be running perfectly. I mean, after the page stops, when I check my db tables, I see records are being inserted (that means my script is still running, but the problem is the page stops loading so I can't see my script result which is feed containing some text).

Comment: Who is your webhost?  It is possible they are ignoring your php.ini settings

Comment: Google around for other users of powweb having the same issues. It's possible that they won't allow you to extend this.  If this is the case, it's time to look for a new host, or buy a VPS.  May I suggest digitalocean.com for simplicity and price?

Comment: Thanks @portforwardpodcast it seems its powweb's limitation!

Comment: If the script is still running, it sounds more like a client-disconnect problem. Do you give any (flushed) output (even just whitespace) while the processing happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google around for other users of powweb having the same issues. It's possible that they won't allow you to extend this. If this is the case, it's time to look for a new host, or buy a VPS. May I suggest digitalocean.com for simplicity and price?

Comment: I see a lot of people recommending digital ocean these days. The prices do look great and from what I understand they can be imaged and re-imaged so quickly, making them good for all sorts of development.

Comment: You should check them out.  There are various offer codes floating around the internet that give you 10 bucks free, so that's two months to test them out for free.  They are much more simple than amazon IMO and have a lot better performance due to not starving your IOPS

Answer (score 0):

Use following code in Apache in .htaccess file:

```
php_value max_execution_time 200
```